# python3.x importing gi... the path of gi package

Tags: python, gstreamer

I built the gst-python with gstreamer built by myself using cerbero...
When importing gi, there is some error like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 2, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 102, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gst not available
```

By the way, this code works well on my another ubuntu.
so I printed out the path of gi using code added on each ubuntu, then the output were different like this.

#### Works well.

```
>>> gi.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py'
```

#### Doesn't work

```
>>> gi.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py'
```

I not sure this difference of path cause the problem. But I wonder how can I control the install path of gi/override...

Please understand my poor question. I am a newbie on gst-python and python...

```
import gi
print(gi.__file__)
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled **gst** library and the error disappeared:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gst-python
```